# Shrew soft connects to cisco VPN in windows 10 but no traffic passing

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-10, cisco-vpn-client, shrew

Recently I've upgraded to windows 10 and facing a problem with connecting to my workplace cisco vpn. Cisco vpn client refused to work. So I opted to install shrew soft vpn client. It says tunnel enabled but then no traffic seems to pass. I can't ping or do RDP or ssh to the necessary servers.
Can anyone be of any assistance? Thanks in advance.

```
Some logs:
config loaded for site 'IP'
attached to key daemon ...
peer configured
iskamp proposal configured
esp proposal configured
ipcomp proposal configured
client configured
local id configured
remote id configured
pre-shared key configured
bringing up tunnel ...
network device configured
tunnel enabled
```

Comment: Which version of shrew are you using?

Comment: Standard edition of 2.2.2-release.

Comment: I managed reinstalling Shrew and restarting Windows. It actually took a few attempts as I tried with older versions. I finally reinstalled 2.2.2 then had to reboot 2 times and it worked.

Comment: I had already reinstalled several times and rebooted system. But still the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem more often now. In my case reboot solves the issue.

When I go to Network tab and find the counter "Established - 0" I know I need to reboot :(

note I'm using v2.1.7